# Overriding of Twitter Bootstrap not working

Tags: css, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, pug, stylus

I am trying to override the `btn-primary` element of Bootstrap. I do this via a local file `/public/styles.css`.

I have used both Jade and Stylus. I cannot however, change the `background-color` of the `btn-primary`.

**Any ideas why?**

```
doctype 5
html(lang="en")
 head
   link(rel='stylesheet',href='http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css')
   title=pageTitle
   link(rel='stylesheet',href='http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css')
   link(rel='stylesheet', href='/public/styles.css')
 body
   h1 MyJade - node template engine
   a(class='btn btn-large btn-primary', href='/profile') Large Button
```

**Where `/public/styles.css` is**:

```
.btn-primary {
  background-color: black;
}
```

But the background color of the button remains the default blue of Bootstrap.

I tried using the `style` tag with exactly the same code in the Jade file and that works, but this does not.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the css file, you'll notice that there is a background-image gradient that is set that over-rides the color

Try

```
.btn-primary {
  background-color: black;
  background-image: none;
}
```

Comment: that didn't seem to work. I think there is a problem finding the specified public/styles.css file, but I don't know what it is. I am running this via a browser while ssh'd to an amazon ec2 instance.